# Parsing JSON variables on Instagram

Tags: json, instagram

I am trying to get all the JSON variables and values from an Instagram page

IE: view-source:http://instagram.com/justinbieber

Are there any functions that you guys recommend?

I tried using json_decode but not all of the page is json - it will only return null for me

Comment: try `jbieber_decode` it's a special one `;)`

Comment: lmao... this is a serious question.  im just using that one since its more of a public page

Comment: check this git https://github.com/cftp/wp-instagram-widget/blob/master/wp-instagram-widget.php

Comment: Hi meda, thanks, but i need more than just photos

Comment: I advice you to check the API docs, instead of scraping the instagram page http://instagram.com/developer/, and here is a demo http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: I have looked into that also but the API is very limited to what I want.  There is much more info in the JSON page itself

Comment: Please be specific about what you need, maybe I can help you parse the data

Comment: JSON variables: followed_by, profile_picture, website, full_name

I know the API would work but it is limited to public profiles only.  I need that accessible even when the profile is private

Comment: ended up using new DOMXPath

Comment: Cool is it all working

Comment: yes meda, thanks i am getting all the json data I need lols

Comment: great if you share your solution I will upvote `;-)`

Comment: post it as an answer!

Comment: I cannot post the answer as my rep is too low...

"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 4/28/2014 10:54:41 PM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Will do later!

Answer (score 0):

```
$instagram_url="http://instagram.com/justinbieber";

$html = file_get_contents($instagram_url)
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$js = $xpath->query('//body/script')->item(1)->nodeValue;
$start = strpos($js, '{');
$end = strrpos($js, ';');
$json = substr($js, $start, $end - $start);

var_dump ($json);
```